# Should I give the party a treasure that is not mentioned anywhere in the adventure content?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league

In DDEX1-1 (Defiance in Phlan), the treasure section in the fourth mini adventure states:

> Buhrell Caah thanks the characters for their assistance, and offers them 100 gp for helping. He wants to take the dragon tooth back to his Emerald Enclave peers for observation. It is obviously too dangerous to leave with others. If the characters willingly give up the tooth, he offers them a potion of healing. If they do not give up the tooth, then a character can keep it, but it’s a bane for them if they have it for more than a day – it grants them vulnerability to lightning damage. 
> Finally, he tells them that he has been keeping an eye on the guilds. They have been gaining more and more power in the city recently, and it might be a good idea to watch out for them in the coming weeks and months.

---

> The characters receive the following treasure, divided up amongst the party. [...]
>
> Reward from Buhrrel Caah 100 gold
>   **Small tourmaline gem** 50 gold

Usually, the treasure here is a list of keepable items from those that the party found. So, if the party does not find an item listed here, that means they missed it(for example, an item hidden in a secret stash, which they never found).

However, I can't find this item in the mini adventure. No NPC has it, let alone gives it to the party, yet it is listed in the treasure section.

If I find an item listed as treasure like this, that's not mentioned anywhere in the adventure as being given to the PCs, **must I still give the item to the party at the end of adventure?**

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to the Adventurer's League?

Comment: @goodguy5 I'm not sure what you mean by reaching out to the Adventurer's League?

Comment: http://dndadventurersleague.org/contact-us/

Comment: Are we sure this isn't just poor formatting and that Buhrrel Caah is actually giving a reward of coin and a gem to the party? I am not too familiar with AL formatting so just asking if that is a possibility.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason I was having difficulty putting-in spoiler markers on that, too... hmm...

Comment: It was the carriage returns... You have to have a tag for each line I think, at least that is how I got it to work. Also there was an extra hard return in there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't have to distribute treasure not "earned". The treasure section is the list of all possible loot, not all divvied loot.

As an example (from earlier in the module, with Brother Keefe), the players can find a secret compartment, holding a small tourmaline (which I assume this is a copy-paste typo from) and a scroll.

Both the scroll and the tourmaline are listed under Treasure, but are possible to be missed by the players (and therefore: not distributed).

On Page 13 of the DDAL DM FAQ (v7.1)

> It depends. As a general rule, if it is found in an adventure, the characters can take it. Whether or not they can keep it is another matter. 
>  **Nonmagical Items.** Only treasure and equipment specifically listed under a treasure subheading can be kept (and converted into gp) by the characters. Items not listed under a treasure subheading may be taken by the characters, but at the conclusion of the session, such items either crumble to dust, break, are lost, or are rendered useless—they can’t be used, sold, or otherwise kept.

This tells us that players can get loot they find, and they can only keep loot in the treasure table.

#### Since there is no way to find the small tourmaline, there is no way to award it.

<sub>P.S. - I still recommend [reaching out to DDAL](http://dndadventurersleague.org/contact-us/) to let them know.</sub>